# ¿Por qué no funciona la condición else?

Tags: javascript, else

La finalidad de esta función es que el usuario te da los parámetros, ejem (prueba2([2,2],[[1,1],[3,2],[0,2]])) y si algún arreglo de immunePoints se parece a la variable right entonces agrega un 1 al arreglo incluideRight y si no se parece entonces agrega un 0
El problema es que aunque alguno de los valores se parezco no agrega el valor 1

```
function prueba2(infectedPoints, immunePoints){
incluideRight = [];
x= infectedPoints[0]
y = infectedPoints[1]
right = [x+1,y];
for (i = 0; i < immunePoints.length; i++){
  if (immunePoints[i] !== right){
console.log(immunePoints[i])
    incluideRight.push(0)
  }else {
    incluideRight.push(1)
  }
  };
console.log(incluideRight);
console.log(right);
};
```

Comment: inmunePoints[i] !== right , siempre se va a cumplir , ya q estas comparando dos tipos diferentes , right es un array.

Comment: Como? perdón soy nuevo en esto de js
No importa que immunePoints sea un array?

Comment: Hola Juan Alfredo. ¿Quieres comprobar que los dos arrays sean iguales? Un saludo y bienvenido

Comment: Hola Jakintsu, si efectivamente

Comment: Y funciona?  Le falta ; en muchos lugares.

Comment: En JavaScript, los punto y coma (;) no son necesarios para marcar el fin de una sentencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues si lo que quieres es comprobar que los dos arrays sean iguales, no lo estás haciendo correctamente, ya que immunePoints[i] no es un array, es otra cosa, por lo que esa condición siempre va a ser true. Si quieres comprobar que dos arrays son iguales, te recomiendo una función como la siguiente:

```
function comprobarArrays(arr1, arr2){
   var contador = arr1.length;

   if (contador  != arr2.length) return false;

   while (contador--) {
     if (arr1[contador ] !== arr2[contador]) return false;
   }
   return true;
 };
```

Y con esta función, trabajaría de la siguiente manera:

```
function prueba2(infectedPoints, immunePoints){
    incluideRight = [];
    x= infectedPoints[0];
    y = infectedPoints[1];
    right = [x+1,y];

   if(!comprobarArrays(inmunePoints, right)){

    console.log(immunePoints[i]);
    incluideRight.push(0);
    } else {
     incluideRight.push(1);
   }

  ......
```

Si he entendido bien tu código y pregunta, claro. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo la variable right es un arreglo y la estás comparando con otro dato, así que la comparación que estás estableciendo SIEMPRE será true. Entendí levemente tu código, pero la solución sería establecer la comparación con datos similares:

```
function prueba2(infectedPoints, immunePoints){
    incluideRight = [];
    x= infectedPoints[0]
    y = infectedPoints[1]
    right = [x+1,y];
    for (i = 0; i < immunePoints.length; i++){
         if (immunePoints[i] !== right[i]){
            console.log(immunePoints[i])
            incluideRight.push(0)
        }else {
            incluideRight.push(1)
       }
    };
    console.log(incluideRight);
    console.log(right);
};
```

O la otra alternativa es en ves de
immunePoints[i] !== right[i]
Sería
immunePoints !== right